# Review low quality posts [ looks good ]

Tags: support, review-page

**Review low quality posts**

Sometimes I see one of those one-line-answers and I write a comment below.
But after reviewing I have to click one of these options: **Looks good** - **Edit** - **Improve** - **Skip**

What should I click after adding a comment?
Is that **Looks good** because I don't want the answer to be removed?
Or is it **Skip**?

Both doesn't look right to me, as I wrote a comment thus not skipping that review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the naming of the options is confusing here.

The solution you want is Looks Good.

Basically Looks Good means I have reviewed the post and taken all the actions I can do. Skip always means I don't know what do to here - leave this in queue for another reviewer.

See this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143469/in-the-new-review-beta-what-does-the-looks-good-button-actually-do) about what the buttons do and this [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147867/late-answers-and-first-posts-encouraging-unnecessary-actions) for why this came about

Comment: That was exactly why I was in doubt. I didn't want to skip, but it doesn't look good either.

The **I'm Done** option suites better IMO